# Set Theory Computer Science A-Level Question Confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying for a Computer Science Degree and am using the book "Essential Maths Skills for AS/A-Level Computer Science" by Gavin Craddock and am on the Set Theory portion.

There is a practice question that states:

If:

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
B = {2,4,6,8}
C = {6,7,8,9}
```

Calculate:

```
(C ∩ B) \ A
```

I work this out as:

```
1. (C ∩ B) = {6,8}
2. {6,8} \ {1,2,3,4,5,6} = {8}
```

However the answer paper gives this as an empty set `{}` or `Ø`

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are right...

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for confirming guys. I am emailing the publisher now.